# Unable to sort data using react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to sort the data and display it is sorted form after user clicks on dropdown button. I want to sort it based on `funds` i.e integer value. So I have added `onClick` on `<a>` tag but it is not working why so ?

**home.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sortByFunded } from '../../store/actions/sortAction';

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    const { searchTermChanged, sortByFunded } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="buttonContainer">
          <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary mycustom dropdown-toggle mr-4" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false">Sort by </button>

            <div className="dropdown-menu">
              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">End time</a>
              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={sortByFunded}>Percentage fund</a>
              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Number of backers</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  projects: state.search.projects,
  sort: state.sort.projects
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchTermChanged, sortByFunded })(Home);
```

**sortAction.js**:

```
import { SORT_BY_FUNDED } from './types';

export const sortByFunded = () => ({
    type: SORT_BY_FUNDED
});
```

**sortReducer.js**:

```
import { SORT_BY_FUNDED } from '../actions/types';
import Projects from '../../data/projects';

const initialState = {
  projects: Projects
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SORT_BY_FUNDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        projects: Projects ? Projects.sort((a, b) => a.funded - b.funded) : Projects
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

projects.js:

```
export default [  
    {  
       "s.no":0,
       "amt.pledged":15823,
       "blurb":"'Catalysts, Explorers & Secret Keepers: Women of Science Fiction' is a take-home exhibit & anthology by the Museum of Science Fiction.",
       "by":"Museum of Science Fiction",
       "country":"US",
       "currency":"usd",
       "endTime":"2016-11-01T23:59:00-04:00",
       "location":"Washington, DC",
       "funded":186,
       "backers":"219382",
       "state":"DC",
       "title":"Catalysts, Explorers & Secret Keepers: Women of SF",
       "type":"Town",
       "url":"/projects/1608905146/catalysts-explorers-and-secret-keepers-women-of-sf?ref=discovery"
    },
    {  
       "s.no":1,
       "amt.pledged":6859,
       "blurb":"A unique handmade picture book for kids & art lovers about a nervous monster who finds his courage with the help of a brave little girl",
       "by":"Tyrone Wells & Broken Eagle, LLC",
       "country":"US",
       "currency":"usd",
       "endTime":"2016-11-25T01:13:33-05:00",
       "location":"Portland, OR",
       "funded":8,
       "backers":"154926",
       "state":"OR",
       "title":"The Whatamagump (a hand-crafted story picture book)",
       "type":"Town",
       "url":"/projects/thewhatamagump/the-whatamagump-a-hand-crafted-story-picture-book?ref=discovery"
    }, ..... ]
```

Comment: can you share the sample data of `Projects`?

Comment: FWIW, I would use a selector (reselect) to do the sorting instead of sorting the data in state. I tend to think of state as the raw data store and selectors transform that data into the display state. So store both the sort and projects in state and then transform them in the selector.

Comment: It's also not a great practice to import something (sortByFunded) and then have a variable with the same name.

Comment: @KeithRousseau If it is not good practice can you please tell what are good practice for naming variables in react redux.  Can you share any guide or resources ?

Comment: Basically you don't want making clashes otherwise you have to think about the scope to know what the variable name means. Just use import as to rename the function in import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my current implementation I was not actually storing Projects in your reducer, but always pulling it from the source when sorting. Also mutating it.

Working code:

reducer.js:

```
import { SORT_BY_FUNDED } from '../actions/types';
import Projects from '../../data/projects';

const initialState = {
    projects: Projects
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SORT_BY_FUNDED:
            return {
            ...state,
            projects: state.projects.length > 0 ? [...state.projects.sort((a,b) => a.funded - b.funded)] : state.projects
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your Reducer is implemented incorrectly. You probably want to check if the `state.project` exists and not the imported `Projects`

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SORT_BY_FUNDED:
      let projects = state.projects ? state.projects : Projects;
      return {
        ...state,
        projects: projects.sort((a, b) => a.funded - b.funded)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```